# Check the password of a user

Tags: password

I want to keep a check if the user has a particular password, so I have been trying it with `wp_check_password` but the account for which it is checked gets logged out and can't login again till there is a call of `wp_check_password` in the code.

Digging into the code, I found out that it sets the password by using the new hash. and moreover if I am using `wp_check_password( 'hello', md5('hello'), 1 );`, it doesn't even check what is inside the database and returns true. Isn't that a bug?

Any ideas how can I check the user's password?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<strike>Your example works correctly. You are checking if password `hello` matches hashed `hello` - which it naturally does.</strike>

Hadn't thought it through. Your example causes following issue:

1. You check if `hello` matches md5 of `hello` (instead of hash from user's profile).
2. It does and then WP thinks this is correct, but outdated md5 hash - that must be updated.
3. It re-hashes `hello` and updates user with it, locking him out (since his password is now `hello` instead of whatever it was before).

See `wp_authenticate_username_password()` function for extensive example, but basic idea is:

```
$userdata = get_user_by('login', $username);
$result = wp_check_password($password, $userdata->user_pass, $userdata->ID);
```

Comment: But it doesn't match in all circumstances, which is what I assumed the problem was. For one the password hash function is pluggable, so its not necessarily using md5 (actually, I don't think it is by default - the default is phpass).

Comment: @goldenapples it doesn't make sense to override `wp_hash_password()` and leave `wp_check_password()`. Hash mismatch simply won't allow anyone to pass the check, no? :)

Comment: Oh, you're right. `wp_check_password()` will work the way you were using it in your answer. I was referring to his original question, checking 'hello' against the md5 of 'hello', which will fail unless md5 is the algorithm actually being used in `wp_hash_password`...

Comment: @goldenapples native `wp_hash_password()` does support md5 for backwards compatibility, it re-hashes such passwords on check. Now that I think about it this is likely the issue in original question...

Comment: Yeah, if the two passwords given match using md5, wp_check_password will reset the user's password using the current hashing function. So in the original question, since the two passwords given matched, it was changing the user's password to "hello"...

Comment: @Rarst Thanks! This works. And I was wondering why I have to supply the hash myself. Its there to maintain backwards compatibility, right? Else Just the password to check and ID would have suffice.

Comment: @Ashfame password-related function are purposely pluggable and very flexible, so people could build or integrate alternative authentication schemes without much trouble.

Comment: @Rarst You mean its for making it pluggable and not for maintaining backward compatibility with different hashes?

Comment: @Ashfame it is only backwards-compatbile with md5, because that is what WP used in the past.

Comment: @Rarst Yes! That's what I meant. I thought your mention of being it pluggable also had to do with the reason of accepting the hash itself as an argument.

Answer (score 4):

You can grab their hashed password from the database, and compare it to the entry you want to check using [wp_hash_password()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password).

To check if the current user's password matches "hello", try this:

```
if ( $current_user->user_pass == wp_hash_password( 'hello' ) )
```

Comment: `if ( wp_hash_password( $xx_new_password ) != $xx_userinfo->user_pass )` works differently than `if ( !wp_check_password( $xx_new_password, $xx_userinfo->user_pass , $xx_id ) )` Weird! Thanks for helping!

Comment: This is incorrect. `wp_hash_password()` applies (in 2020) a random salt to the password before hashing it, so no two calls to it return the same value.

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpass.php';
$wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);

$password_hashed = '$P$BB3pP6fQAYa61ael0LNQlpB1NOyqNY0';
$plain_password = 'admin2';
if($wp_hasher->CheckPassword($plain_password, $password_hashed)) {
    print 'Password matched.';
}
```

Credits to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37181662